# Remove div by the Id attribute using Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I have a query like I can remove the entire label identifying the Div but Div Id attribute, because the code that I have only do by the order of Div.

```
String baseHtml = "<div id='stylized' class='myform'>"
                 + "<input id='txt_question' name='preg' type='text' disabled='disabled' style='width:150px;'>"
                 + "<div id='detail_question'>Rock</div></div>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(baseHtml);
Elements elements = doc.select("div");
elements.get(1).remove();
elements = doc.select("div");
System.out.println(elements);
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on the requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String baseHtml = "<div id='stylized' class='myform'>"
        + "<input id='txt_question' name='preg' type='text' disabled='disabled' style='width:150px;'>"
        + "<div id='detail_question'>Rock</div></div>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(baseHtml);
doc.getElementById("detail_question").remove();
Elements elements = doc.select("div");
System.out.println(elements);
```

This line will return the element with id detail_question.

```
doc.getElementById("detail_question")
```

Element can be removed, so with chaining you have

```
doc.getElementById("detail_question").remove()
```